Evidence for the size of the nucleus
As a non-physicist, I find it hard to believe that the nucleus of the atom truly is so much smaller than the atom as a whole. What other evidence is there, apart from the gold foil experiment, to confirm that the nucleus really is that small?
To me, the conclusions derived from the gold foil experiment seem quite arbitrary and based on thinking that applies to macroscopic objects rather than subatomic particles.
Edit: this is not a duplicate of Measuring nucleons using electron beams. Here I'm asking about any convincing evidence physics has for the size of the nucleus, not necessarily from scattering experiments.

Related - Electron scattering to measure the nuclear radius.

This question is similar to: Measuring nucleons using electron beams. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi, @JohnRennie. Your answer under that other question is certainly helpful, thanks, but please consider reopening my question, as I'd like to have the input of other physicists here as well, perhaps with evidence from experiments other than scattering experiments, if there is any.

I won't use my moderator superpower to reopen this question, but I have a nice answer in mind. Position-momentum uncertainty and the scales of energy levels; meson masses and the Yukawa interaction; the prediction of neutron star densities; the fact that the question itself uses "size" in at least two ways, whose difference is not really understandable outside of quantum mechanics. The current list of duplicates suggests that electron scattering is the only evidence for the nuclear size, which just isn't correct.

@rob #ModSuperPower

Welcome Java Castaway to Physics SE. I am voting to reopen the closer duplicate "How might we measure the size of a proton? (Without high energy collisions). The latter question does not arbitrarily dismiss the overwhelming evidence from more than a century of electron, muon, photon, proton, antiproton, neutrino, pion, alpha, heavy ion, … scattering experiments that measure the nuclear size. A relevant answer is given by "Measuring the size of the proton from the hydrogen atom spectrum?".

Voting to reopen so Rob can answer. The answer sounds useful.

I voted to keep this one closed since I think it would be better to reopen and let Rob answer the earlier - and in my opinion better - duplicate question I noted in my earlier comment.

Various people here talking about whether the question should be open or closed, but so far, the OP themself has not spoken. @JavaCastaway, You say that you "find it hard to believe...," but why is it hard for you to believe? What do you know about atoms that seems contrary to the idea that the size of their nucleii is so much smaller than the distance between them in normal matter?

Sorry for being a bit late, we were quite busy at work and I didn't have time to meditate on physics :) @Ohm'sLawman mostly the few things I learned about particles, like the fact that they behave like waves in some scenarios, such as the double-slit experiment; and that there are quantum effects like quantum tunnelling. How could I be certain that Rutherford, performing his experiments more than 100 years ago, came to correct conclusions about the nature of matter? rob, thanks for the comment, that's the kind of answer I was looking for :) [1/2]

What bugs me with regards to the gold foil experiment is that Rutherford's conclusions seem to rest on shaky ground. I mean, even with Thomson's model it is predictable that most alpha particles fired at the foil would pass right through. My understanding is that what Rutherford found, in addition, is that a tiny, tiny fraction of particles bounce back or at an angle. Okay, a few bounce back, so... what, really? How does that prove that the nucleus is extremely small? But I'm not a physicist, so feel free to roast me :) I'll try to read the actual paper of Rutherford as well.
